# Remove comments from file

Tags: plugins, ide, source-code, phpstorm

I'm using PHPStorm and have a very basic problem. I want to remove single/multi/phpdoc comments from my files. I want this process to be one-click and easily undo-able. I've tried looking over the internet and in PHPStorm help but couldn't find any feature like this.

There could be a PHPStorm plugin that performs this function? I've exhausted my resources in trying to find out the answer.

I know I can use regular expression search replace in PHPStorm and other text editors to achieve this but I'm looking for more of a one click do/undo able solution.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since the problem in this question hasn't received any solutions, I; for documentation and readers' help, am going to present the way I currently do it. The ideal solution has to be one-click and do following

1. remove all comments in one click
2. restore all comments back in one click

So my less than ideal solution is as follows

**Remove all comments**
 1. use following regexp in find tool to replace all multi-line comments with empty `/\*(\*)?(((?!\*/)[\s\S])+)?\*/`
 2. **then** use following regexp to replace all single-line comments with empty `//.*$`

**Restore all comments**
 1. Open `VCS > Local History > Show History` and restore to the version with comments.

I'm still hoping to find a true one-click solution.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [PhpStorm 9.0.0 Help / Commenting and Uncommenting Blocks of Code](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/commenting-and-uncommenting-blocks-of-code.html):

**Commenting and uncommenting lines of code**

Do one of the following:

```
On the main menu, choose Code | Comment with Line Comment.
Press Ctrl+Slash.
```

**Commenting and uncommenting blocks of code**

To add or remove a block comment, do one of the following:

```
On the main menu, choose Code | Comment with Block Comment.
Press Ctrl+Shift+Slash.
```

Comment: That serves a different purpose than I've stated in question. I want to remove the comment contents which is different from uncommenting a block and making it part of the code.

Answer (score 0):

PHPStorm doesn't come with any predefined functions/plugins for deleting comments.
The most obvious solution is regexp replacement. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503871/best-way-to-automatically-remove-comments-from-php-code, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22819768/removing-php-comments-with-replace-tool-using-regex-in-phpstorm for some hints.

Comment: That's how I currently do it.